# Can regular PDFs be converted into editable PDF forms?

Tags: pdf, forms

It seems Word documents can be made into editable PDF forms, but I'm having trouble finding any literature about taking a pre-existing PDF and making the form fields editable.

I have a long PDF that's meant to be printed and filled in by hand. For archival purposes, I'd much rather fill it in digitally, print it, and sign it.

As a last resort I can just use simple image manipulation to drop text over the appropriate areas, but if I can add form fill-in capability to this PDF I'd very much like to, both for convenience's sake and as a learning experience.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a PDF editor like Adobe Acrobat.  What many folks mistake for Acrobat is really just Acrobat Reader.  That is free while their "Acrobat" or "Acrobat Pro" software costs.  If you want a free PDF editor, try something like this http://www.freepdfeditor.net/